# Could not bind properties to JHipsterProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using JHipster 7.9.3 in my current project using Java 11, Spring Boot 2.7. We are now in the process of upgrading to Jhipster 8.0.0-rc.1, Java 17, Spring Boot 3 and Spring Framework 6.

When I start the application I see this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigurer' defined in file [mypath/WebConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jhipster-tech.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties': Could not bind properties to 'JHipsterProperties' : prefix=jhipster, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false
```

In WebConfigurer file, we have the following constructor

```
    public WebConfigurer(Environment env, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.env = env;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }
```

In application.yml

```
jhipster:
  clientApp:
    name: 'myapp'
..
..
```

This works in the previous working version, I am not able to figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: I had jhipster.logging.logstash.queue-size in my application.yml. Changing it to jhipster.logging.logstash.ring-buffer-size fixed the issue. Looks like the queue-size is deprected in the newer version.